# R Tidy method for creating factor variable based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataset like this:

```
Gender<-c("Male","Female","Male","Male","Female")
PlaceA<-c("","","","1600","")
PlaceB<-c("","200","211","326","")
PlaceC<-c("1111","2222","","","45")
PlaceD<-c("1000","","","1600","210")
DF<-tibble(Gender,PlaceA,PlaceB,PlaceC,PlaceD)
```

I'd like to create a new variable that is categorical, and based on several rules about the "place_" variables.

For example:
This new variable could be called "category" and would behave like so:

- If there is ANYTHING in "PlaceA", this new "category" variable would be "First"
- If they only have values in PlaceC and PlaceD, they are "Second"
- If they only have values in PlaceB they are "Third"
- If there is a larger number in Place C than PlaceB they are "Fourth"
- There will be a few more rules like that
- If they didn't fit any of the other rules they are "last"
- In the real data there shouldn't be overlap between cases fitting two different scenarios, but if there is I can deal with that later.

Any ideas?   If there was never overlap I'd think gather and spread, but since there will be times where there are values in both, or I am comparing numbers to each other, I was at a loss.

Comment: have you tried using `case_when`?

Comment: As @IceCreamToucan mentioned, `case_when` should work here, just be careful that you start listing the conditions from most specific to most general - see the "fuzz buzz" example here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html